# Code which can drop CRL

Tags: c#, .net

Got question on interview about how to drop JVM and I know that it is possible by java code. But what about dropping CRL on machine by few code lines?

Comment: What does "drop JVM"/"dropping CRL" mean?

Comment: Stops to work by some unexpected operation.